# Overriding style in CSS?

Tags: html, css

JSfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/s3king93/tXuLD/

Trying to style the individual class .home1 to always have the same grey background as a:hover. For some reason the style won't override, even when I use !important. If I take away the a:hover part the background shows up but the text doesn't.

Anybody have any ideas?

```
<div class="list-1">
            <ul class="list-style-1">
                <li><a class="home1" href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">INFLUENCES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CLASSES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ANDREWS VIDEO BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


.list-1 {
padding:none;
float: right;
clear:right;
padding-right: 27px ;

}

.list-style-1 {
padding-top: 26px;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: "Bell Gothic Std Light";
font-size: 20px;


}

 a { 
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 1px;
}

a:link {

text-decoration:none;
color: #2A2A2A;

}

 a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
color: #2A2A2A;
}

 a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color: #69E0F6;
background: #2A2A2A;

}

a:active {

text-decoration:none;
color: #69E0F6;
background: #2A2A2A;
}



.home1 a:link {

text-decoration:none;
color: #69E0F6;
background: #2A2A2A;

}
```

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tXuLD/1/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
a.home1 {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #69E0F6;
  background: #2A2A2A;
}
```

Comment: When I try that the HOME text goes grey also? I'm using chrome.

Comment: Not seeing that. @j08691's JSFiddle shows what I'm seeing - http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tXuLD/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.home1 a:link {

text-decoration:none;
color: #69E0F6;
background: #2A2A2A;

}
```

`home1` is on the `<a>` tag, try `a.home1` or just `.home1` alone
you can mix in `.home1:hover` -- `.home1:active` 
if you kept your way `class="home1"` would need to be on the `<li>` on an ancestor element somewhere as [ajp15243](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883647/ajp15243) points out.

Comment: The `home1` class wouldn't necessarily have to be on the parent `li` tag, just on any of the ancestor tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
.home1  {
    background: #2a2a2a !important;
    color: #69E0F6 !important;
}
```

And my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/tXuLD/28/)

Comment: When I try that the HOME text goes grey also?

Comment: copy the css in my jfiddle, onto your page and see if that works for you.

Comment: when you try this code, the background for HOME will be the dark grey, and the color for the text will be blue. Is that what you want?